# ember.js on one template with load - routing issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js

what is meant to happen is

go to `myurl.com`  and the home template is seen with no url change

or go to `myurl.com#/h` then load the home template
or go to `myurl.com#/a` then load the about template

but it will now only load the home template. please can you help.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){

    this.resource('home', {path: '/h'} );
    this.resource('about', {path: '/a'} );
    this.resource('contact', {path: '/c'} );
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('home', {});
  }
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.ContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `this.resource('home', {path: '/'} );` for your home route. Now, when you visit `/`, the home template will be rendered.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/pu8AR/)